# How to create a product configurator for an eCommerce store?

Tags: html, magento, e-commerce, dynamic-html

I want to implement a configurator for an eCommere store.
It should basically look like this: http://urbike.de/singlespeed/Konfigurator.html.

I do not have much experience in web design, what do I need to create such a configurator for an eCommerce store. Are there any simple solutions?

Comment: I think that you have to contract with a web graphic designer. You may find one @ http://www.freelancer.com

Comment: my graphic design skills are sufficient. i am actually talking about the technical implementation of an ecommerce product configurator

Comment: I'd to mention that Web Graphic Designer is not only a matter of graphics. It includes some client-side techniques such as Jquery, css, Javascript and flash in general.

Comment: if i need it, i'll learn it. just need to know what exactly i need to have a systematic approach.

Comment: You will need to learn the following in order:
1- HTML
2-CSS
3-Javascript
4- Jquery

Then using Jquery you have to know how to deal with draggable.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this in magento would be

1. Create a simple product
2. Add 'Custom Option' for each option (eg Frame color, Fork, Front wheel...) with up-charges (if any)
3. Create the Images using one of the 2 methods below

   1. Creating a image for each possible combination and use a file naming convention (downside - thousands of images)
   2. Create a transparent image for each option/layer (eg. fork, front wheel) in each color, then use css to overlay them on to each other (layers must be in the correct order)
4. Create javascript functionality to change the images base on current selection and load the default config and reload current option if user choose to edit item in their cart
5. You will have to think about how intuitive you want the admin section to be. Should a 'Admin' user be able to upload the all these images and assign color swatches when configuring the product (or just ftp them to the server)
6. Think about if you want to display their current config image on order confirmation or just a default image

What you are tying to accomplish is fairly complex, from my past experience of creating simpler features it's going to require a lot of external js coding and knowledge on how magento simple product js work.